# Select query with optional condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to achieve **Case 3**:

**Case 1:** Customer is registered but did not placed an order yet. The query gives result for case 1.

```
    SELECT c.customers_id, 
       c.customers_firstname, 
       c.customers_lastname, 
       c.customers_email_address, 
       c.customers_telephone, 
       c.customers_fax, 
       ab.entry_street_address, 
       ab.entry_city, 
       ab.entry_state, 
       ab.entry_country_id, 
       ab.entry_postcode 
FROM   customers c 
       JOIN address_book ab 
         ON c.customers_id = ab.customers_id 
       JOIN customers_info ci 
         ON c.customers_id = ci.customers_info_id 
WHERE  ci.customers_info_date_account_created BETWEEN 
       '2014-10-25' AND '2015-10-10'
```

**Case 2:** Customer is registered and also has placed an order. This query is getting additional delivery information from orders table. The following query works for case 2.

```
SELECT c.customers_id, 
       c.customers_firstname, 
       c.customers_lastname, 
       c.customers_email_address, 
       c.customers_telephone, 
       c.customers_fax, 
       ab.entry_street_address, 
       ab.entry_city, 
       ab.entry_state, 
       ab.entry_country_id, 
       ab.entry_postcode, 
       o.delivery_street_address, 
       o.delivery_city, 
       o.delivery_state, 
       o.delivery_country, 
       o.delivery_postcode 
FROM   customers c 
       JOIN address_book ab 
         ON c.customers_id = ab.customers_id 
       JOIN orders o 
         ON c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
WHERE  o.date_purchased BETWEEN '2014-10-25' AND '2015-10-10'
```

**Case 3(What I am trying to achieve):** I want to get all customers registered between certain time period using

ci.customers_info_date_account_created BETWEEN '2014-10-25' and '2015-10-10'

Also, I want to check if order is placed by the customer using o.date_purchased BETWEEN '2014-10-25' and '2015-10-10'. If order is placed, then get all delivery information from orders table. If no order is placed, then leave these columns empty.

o.delivery_street_address, o.delivery_city, o.delivery_state, o.delivery_country, o.delivery_postcode

Comment: It would be great if you can include sample data and desired output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT c.customers_id, 
       c.customers_firstname, 
       c.customers_lastname, 
       c.customers_email_address, 
       c.customers_telephone, 
       c.customers_fax, 
       ab.entry_street_address, 
       ab.entry_city, 
       ab.entry_state, 
       ab.entry_country_id, 
       ab.entry_postcode,
       o.delivery_street_address, o.delivery_city, o.delivery_state, o.delivery_country, o.delivery_postcode  
FROM   customers c 
       INNER JOIN address_book ab 
         ON c.customers_id = ab.customers_id 
       INNER JOIN customers_info ci 
         ON c.customers_id = ci.customers_info_id
       LEFT JOIN (select * from orders where date_purchased BETWEEN '2014-10-25' AND '2015-10-10') o
         ON c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
WHERE  ci.customers_info_date_account_created BETWEEN 
       '2014-10-25' AND '2015-10-10'
```

You can list the field names instead of * in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Change `JOIN orders o` to `LEFT JOIN orders o` (which will fill a NULL row), then change your condition to

```
WHERE (o.date_purchased BETWEEN '2014-10-25' AND '2015-10-10' OR o.customers_id IS NULL)
```

That will find anyone with an order in that timeframe, or customers that have not yet placed an order.

Comment: I find it easier to put the `date_purchased` condition in the `ON` clause, so you don't need the `IS NULL` test.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`. This will return rows from the first table that don't have any match in the second table.

```
SELECT c.customers_id, 
       c.customers_firstname, 
       c.customers_lastname, 
       c.customers_email_address, 
       c.customers_telephone, 
       c.customers_fax, 
       ab.entry_street_address, 
       ab.entry_city, 
       ab.entry_state, 
       ab.entry_country_id, 
       ab.entry_postcode, 
       o.delivery_street_address, 
       o.delivery_city, 
       o.delivery_state, 
       o.delivery_country, 
       o.delivery_postcode 
FROM   customers c 
JOIN address_book ab 
    ON c.customers_id = ab.customers_id 
JOIN customer_info ci
    ON c.customers_id = ci.customers_info_id
LEFT JOIN orders o 
    ON c.customers_id = o.customers_id AND o.date_purchased BETWEEN '2014-10-25' AND '2015-10-10' 
WHERE ci.customers_info_date_account_created BETWEEN '2014-10-25' AND '2015-10-10'
```

The confition on `o.date_purchased` gets moved into the `ON` clause, because the `NULL` values that are returned from the non-matching rows would not match the `BETWEEN` clause.

Comment: Yeah, yours is much cleaner -- I had a hard time understanding his queries before his edit. :)

Comment: Thanks, barmar. I was trying something similar but with outer join.

Comment: @Jas LEFT JOIN **is** OUTER JOIN.